# Best way to import coordinates from .gpx file and display using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a mountain biker and I track my rides on my `Samsung S3 Galaxy` using programs such as `Endomondo` and `Strava`.  Everything regarding my ride is saved on these 2 websites.

I have my own personal website where I display mountain routes in various areas where I stay. The route data recorded via `GPS` using Endomondo and Strava I have exported to a `.gpx` file.  I need this data in the .gpx file to display on my own personal website. So I started to look for a solution using the `Google Maps API` and importing the .gpx file without using an external tool.

I struggled to find an answer. I came across this post where the guy uses `jQuery` to extract the data in the XML file and to display this data on his Google map:
http://www.jacquet80.eu/blog/post/2011/02/Display-GPX-tracks-using-Google-Maps-API

This is how implemented it into my HTML markup:

```
<script>
     function initialize() {
          var route1Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7610590,18.9616790);
          var mapOptions = {
               center: route1Latlng,
               zoom: 11,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

          $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "gpx/my_route.gpx",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function (xml) {
                    var points = [];
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function () {
                         var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
                         var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
                         var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                         points.push(p);
                         bounds.extend(p);
                    });
                    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                         // use your own style here
                         path: points,
                         strokeColor: "#FF00AA",
                         strokeOpacity: .7,
                         strokeWeight: 4
                    });
                    poly.setMap(map);
                    // fit bounds to track
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
               }
          });
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

It works. But is this the correct way to do it? Is there a better a way to implement this?

Answer (score 6):

**Update for 2020**

Works with Google Map's latest API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Map</title>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        function initMap() {    
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: { lat: 0, lng: -180 },
                mapTypeId: "satellite",
                disableDefaultUI: true,
            });
                      
            fetch('2020-10-12_2007.gpx')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
                //.then(data => console.log(data))
                .then(doc =>
                {
                    var points = [];
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                
                    const nodes = [...doc.getElementsByTagName('trkpt')];
                    nodes.forEach(node =>
                    {
                        var lat = node.getAttribute("lat");
                        var lon = node.getAttribute("lon");
                        //console.log(lat);
                        
                        var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                        points.push(p);
                        bounds.extend(p);
                    })
                    
                    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                             path: points,
                             strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                             strokeOpacity: 1,
                             strokeWeight: 4
                        });
                        poly.setMap(map);
                        // fit bounds to track
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                })
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use PostgreSQL database, I'd suggest you to use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) and import your records to the database. Then you can easily generate kml files ([ST_asKml](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsKML.html)) and display them on Google Map. If your gpx is huge, you can use [ST_Simplify](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html) on a database query so that the page is loaded faster and you still have full detailed route in your database.

You also have a lot of possibilities:

- search for rides in a specified area
- measure total distance in a month
- and much more

Comment: I'm actually using SQL Server. Why would you suggest that I use KML files if I already have them as .gpx?

Comment: When generating kml from database, you can easily display more routes on the same map. It's also easier to style the route using kml styles.

Comment: Kml is the "google way" to store and display geographic data, and both GMaps and GEarth have good support for importing and exporting kml instead of gpx. Also, it's very natural to convert between GPX and KML using tools like, for example, GPSBabel, or even a hack in your favorite language (python, php, etc.)

Comment: @heltonbiker Kml is though not the most popular format and a lot of people not get happy by 'google way'. To my understanding, you can loose information when this conversion happens, such as environmental data etc.